# How to remove fonts.googleapis from magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.6, openmage

I have in my theme template file head.phtml, and here is added:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400,600,italic,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

So question is how to remove it through my template layout local.xml? or maybe another method?

Or maybe to delete it with JS?

Comment: Create another theme, copy the file to the theme, and remove the line there. For more info, google "magento 1.9 infinite theme fallback".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the link was added directly to the template you cannot use layout instructions to remove it. You will need to either modify the template directly (not recommended if this is a template inside one of the core themes) or using your custom theme (if you don't have one you can make one and extend your current theme) to override the head.phtml template and remove it there.